# OSX: Remap caps lock key to funktion key or Fn?

Tags: macos, keyboard, sublimetext2

I already disabled the caps lock key but to actually use the key in my text editor as a kind of special key, I would like to remap the key to the function key or to F19 for example.

How can I remap the key to a different key other than command, option or shift?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'd like to do the same...

Answer (score 1):

The only viable solution I've found was to use a program called Karabiner-Elements: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/
With it you can define a "simple modification" to remap CapsLock to Fn.

Answer (score 0):

In OSX, you can do this OS-wide. Go to system-preferences and choose keyboard.  Under the "keyboard" tab, find the <kbd>Modifier Keys...</kbd> button.  I always set `caps lock` to be another instance of `control`.